# Author and date in the lower left corner on the title page

Tags: positioning, titles

I'd like to have the author, the date and other things in the lower left corner of the title page. I thought of aligning them in a `tabular`, but how do I place it on the title page?

My Page should Look like this:

```
_____________________________________
|                                   |
|                                   |
|               TITLE               |
|                                   |
|              Subtitle             |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
| Author  name                      |
| Date    date                      |
| ....    ....                      |
_____________________________________
```

Comment: Would you please add more details? Just a schematic view of the data you want on the title page.

Answer (score 6):

You have to create your own layout for the title page, using the environment `titlepage`. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill

  \begin{center}

  {\Huge My Title}
  \vskip 2cm

  {\Large Subtitle or whatever}
  \vskip 1cm

  {\large Institution or whatever}
  \end{center}

\vfill
\vfill

\begin{tabular}{r}
Author Name\\
\small\today\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the rather dull output:

[image: Output]

You can see examples of more interesting titlepages in the collections by [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html) and [Peter Wilson](ftp://ftp.di.uminho.pt/pub/ctan/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf)